# Zero set of the Fourier transform of measures

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ and the Fourier transform of $\mu$ is defined by 
$$ \widehat{\mu}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2\pi i \xi x} ~ d \mu(x). $$
Let $\mathcal{Z}(\widehat{\mu})=\{ \xi \in \mathbb R: \widehat{\mu}(\xi)=0 \}$.

**Question**: how about the set $\mathcal{Z}(\widehat{\mu})$? Can we show that the set $\mathcal{Z}(\widehat{\mu})$ is at most countable?

---

**Try**: when $\mu$ has compact support, we can extend $\widehat{\mu}$ to the whole complex plane by 
$$ \widehat{\mu}(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2\pi i z x} ~ d \mu(x). $$
Next, using compact support, we can show $\widehat{\mu}(z)$ is an entire function. 
By the theorem in complex analysis, we can obtain that the set $\mathcal{Z}(\widehat{\mu})$ has no limit point.

I have no idea of the case when the support of $\mu$ is not compact.

Comment: The characteristic function of probability measure can vanish throughout some inerval. Such examples are available in Feller's book.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you give the name of Feller’s book?

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\phi (t)=1-|t|$ for $|t| \leq 1$ and $0$ for $|t| >1$ is  the Fourier transform of  a probablity measure. This is proved in Feller's book: An  Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications. See the  section on 'Special densities. Mixtures' in the chapter on 'Characterisitic Functions'.